# MAUI colour at the top

Tags: maui

I've created a new MAUI app in VisualStudio 2022 and can't find out how to change the colour of the purple strip at the top of the screen.

I've updated the colours:

```
    <Color x:Key="Primary">#cccccc</Color>
    <Color x:Key="PrimaryDark">#999999</Color>
    <Color x:Key="PrimaryDarkText">#222222</Color>
    <Color x:Key="Secondary">#444444</Color>
    <Color x:Key="SecondaryDarkText">#888888</Color>
    <Color x:Key="Tertiary">#666666</Color>

    <Color x:Key="White">White</Color>
    <Color x:Key="Black">Black</Color>
    <Color x:Key="Magenta">#BBBBBB</Color>
    <Color x:Key="MidnightBlue">#190649</Color>
    <Color x:Key="OffBlack">#1f1f1f</Color>
```

Nowhere in the code is `Shell.BackgroundColor` so it can't be that.

Nowhere in the code appears `TitleBar`.

Where is this purple coming from?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're talking about Android. Check the colors under `Platforms/Android/Resources/values/colors.xml` and play with the values in there.

Unfortunately, Android has their own coloring system like that and its a bit harder to make our XAML colors also show up there. To avoid this confusion we added a little comment to the `Colors.xaml` file at the top `<!-- Note: For Android please see also Platforms\Android\Resources\values\colors.xml -->`.

Definitely some room for improvement there, but this should at least help you going!

Answer (score 0):

I also struggled with this on Android and at the time I had to do the following, just in case Geralds solid Advice does not work for you.

Platforms/Android/Resources - MainActivity.cs

You can add the following method.

```
        // Custom Styling for Android to colour Navigation Bar(Bottom) and System Bar (Top)
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            Window.SetNavigationBarColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor("#335AAA"));
            Window.SetStatusBarColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Black);

            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }
```